# Algorithm to determine the minimal set of coins you should carry to always make exact change

Tags: math, set, mathematical-optimization

US coin values:

.01, .05, .10, .25

What is an algorithm to determine what configuration(s) of US coins can be used to match every value from .01-.99 using the fewest coins possible?

Comment: so... is this a "how would you write a program to find this" kind of question?

Comment: No, this is 'not a real question' kind of question.

Comment: Is this question just a model for the problem you're actually trying to solve, or are you just trying to minimise the time you spend in queues? Not that it changes the answer, I'm just curious.

Comment: To make 99 cents you need 3q2q4p. Add 1p to this mix, and you can make any amount between 1 cent and 1 dollar.